# Convert {key=value, key=value} to {"key":"value", "key":"value"}

Tags: java, json

I have a string that is being returned by an API which looks like this :

```
 String result1 = "{username=null, tokenCode=00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000754d6034}";
```

I converted this to

```
String result2 = "{"username":"null", "tokenCode":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000754d6034"}";
```

Below is the code I am using it to convert to result2 from result1.

```
String result2 = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create().toJson(result1);
```

Again I am doing this to make it a JSON object from String.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result2);
```

Is there a better way I can directly convert the "result1" to JSONObject without having to convert it to "result2".

Comment: Can you contact the API owner and suggest they return valid JSON? That would be the best outcome, for everyone...

Comment: I can not, is there an alternative way to this?

Comment: Well it sounds like you've already got a working approach. Given that what you've started with *isn't JSON* it sounds entirely reasonable that you have to go via something else before creating a `JSONObject`.

Comment: I am surprised that you managed to make it work in the first place. Are you sure that you got the exact result `{username=null, tokenCode=00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000754d6034}` from the API? This looks more like the result of a `toString()` method called on a `HashMap` instance.

Comment: @MCEmperor I am using Google Gson library, it is sweet for this kind of work. Try using Gson, you should be able to reproduce.

Comment: @horizon Well, I suspect that the contents of `result1` you are showing, was not the actual response of the API, but rather the result of some (implicit) `toString()` call. See my previous comment.

Comment: @MCEmperor Yeah actually it is returing a JSON but there is a field (like nested JSON) which has the above value.. like --> field : {username=null, tokenCode=00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000754d6034} so you see the value of key field is in the above format.

Comment: @horizon Still, this looks like a `toString()` call rather than the actual API response. How are you displaying your result? Did you try to use Postman to get the actual API result?

Comment: Yeah on postman its alright (looks exactly how a JSON should look)